# Polar coordinates problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do not understand how it is interpreted by a specified angle when using polar coordinates. I prepared three examples in my MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}                      % TikZ and PGF picture 
     \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
     \usetikzlibrary{calc}
     \usetikzlibrary{positioning}     
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing} 
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htp]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
          \coordinate (B) at (0,1);
          \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
          \node[left, color=blue] at (A) {A};
          \node[left, color=blue] at (B) {B};
          \node[right, color=blue] at (C) {C};
          \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);        
          \draw [color=cyan] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C),
                \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
                (A) -- (\n1:2cm);
          \ExtractCoordinate{B};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2cm) {B $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};
          \ExtractCoordinate{C};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2.5cm) {C $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};          
        \end{tikzpicture} 

        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (A) at (-90.58205pt, 119.0348pt);
          \coordinate (B) at (-90.58205pt, 133.26117pt);
          \coordinate (C) at (-40.43698pt, 119.0348pt);
          \node[left, color=blue] at (A) {A};
          \node[left, color=blue] at (B) {B};
          \node[right, color=blue] at (C) {C};
          \draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);        
          \draw [color=cyan] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C),
                \n1={atan2(abs(\y2-\y1), abs(\x3-\x1))} in
                (B) -- (74.161134732:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=green] (B) -- (0:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=red] (B) -- (45:2cm);        
          \ExtractCoordinate{B};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2cm) {B $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};
          \ExtractCoordinate{C};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2.5cm) {C $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};          
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (A) at (2, 2); 
          \draw[right, color=green] (A) -- (0:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=red] (A) -- (45:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=blue] (A) -- (90:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=black] (A) -- (74.161134732:2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- first example: everything works fine.
- second example: problem:

In the following command:

```
\draw [color=cyan] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C), \n1={atan2(abs(\y2-\y1), abs(\x3-\x1))} in (B) -- (74.161134732:2cm);
```

I tried to calculate the angle so I joined B to C. Unfortunately, unsuccessfully. I thought that atan2 function works wrong, so I replaced value in the variable \n1 by manually calculated angle, but again I did not connect the two points.

I reached to the conclusion that I can not properly use polar coordinates, and so I tried to test everything in the third example. I expected the green line will be horizontal, but instead, the line is vertical.

For illustration, I attach a picture:

[image]

Can you explain where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.  The first is mathematical: the arguments to the  `atan2` are the **x** and then the **y** (I know that this varies from program to program so is something you should always check when using `atan2` functions); also, to get the angle correct you should not take the absolute values as this changes the quadrant at the least.  So the correct syntax for the `atan2` in your second example would be:

```
\draw [color=cyan] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C),
            \n1={atan2(\x3-\x1, \y2-\y1)} in
            (B) -- (\n:2cm);
```

The reason that this doesn't show up in your first example is because both coordinate expressions evaluate to `1` whereupon the order doesn't matter and taking absolute values does nothing.

However, the above is still not right and this is the second error.  You are drawing a line from `(B)` to `(\n:2cm)`.  The second position is specified in **absolute** coordinates and so is a point at `\n` degrees and `2cm` **from the origin**.  You want it to be from `(B)`.  To reorient the coordinate system, you should use *relative* coordinates.  Thus `(B) -- ++(\n:2cm)` gets you what you want.

Again, this doesn't show up in the first example because your point of interest, `(A)` in that case, is located at the origin so relative and absolute coordinates give the same answer.

This is the same mistake in your third example.  The coordinate `(0:2cm)` becomes `(2,0)` which is vertically down from `(A)` (located at `(2,2)`).  To get a horizontal line you need to make it relative: `++(0:2cm)`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}                      % TikZ and PGF picture 
     \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
     \usetikzlibrary{calc}
     \usetikzlibrary{positioning}     
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing} 
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1);
\pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htp]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
          \coordinate (B) at (0,1);
          \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
          \node[left, color=blue] at (A) {A};
          \node[left, color=blue] at (B) {B};
          \node[right, color=blue] at (C) {C};
          \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);        
          \draw [color=cyan] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C),
                \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
                (A) -- (\n1:2cm);
          \ExtractCoordinate{B};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2cm) {B $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};
          \ExtractCoordinate{C};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2.5cm) {C $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};          
        \end{tikzpicture} 

        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (A) at (-90.58205pt, 119.0348pt);
          \coordinate (B) at (-90.58205pt, 133.26117pt);
          \coordinate (C) at (0pt, 119.0348pt);
          \node[left, color=blue] at (A) {A};
          \node[left, color=blue] at (B) {B};
          \node[right, color=blue] at (C) {C};
          \draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);        
          \draw [color=cyan] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C),
                \n1={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y1-\y2)} in
                (B) -- ++(\n1:4cm);
          \draw[right, color=green] (B) -- ++(0:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=red] (B) -- ++(45:2cm);        
          \ExtractCoordinate{B};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2cm) {B $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};
          \ExtractCoordinate{C};
          \node [below] at (1cm,-2.5cm) {C $(\XCoord,\YCoord)$};          
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (A) at (2, 2); 
          \draw[right, color=green] (A) -- ++(0:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=red] (A) -- ++(45:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=blue] (A) -- ++(90:2cm);
          \draw[right, color=black] (A) -- ++(74.161134732:2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: relative polar coordinates]